# Spark create column name based on other column values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and need help in transforming this data in below format:

I have data in this format:

```
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------+---------+------+
|   id     |       values            |     creation date | leadTime| span |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------+---------+--+---+
|id_1      |[[v1, 0.368], [v2, 0.5]] |     2020-07-15    |      16 |  15  |
|id_2      |[[v1, 0.368], [v2, 0.4]] |     2020-07-15    |      16 |  15  |
|id_3      |[[v1, 0.468], [v2, 0.3]] |     2020-07-15    |      16 |  15  |
|id_4      |[[v1, 0.368], [v2, 0.3]] |     2020-07-15    |      16 |  15  |
|id_5      |[[v1, 0.668], [v2, 0.1]] |     2020-07-15    |      16 |  15  |
|id_6      |[[v1, 0.168], [v2, 0.2]] |     2020-07-15    |      16 |  15  |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------+---------+------+
```

I need data in below format by using values from column fields:

creating new column with column name using leadTime and span column value

```
+----------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|   id     |creation date | final_v1_16_15_wk  |  final_v2_16_15_wk |
+----------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|id_1      |2020-07-15    |       0.368        |         0.5        |
|id_2      |2020-07-15    |       0.368        |         0.4        |
|id_3      |2020-07-15    |       0.468        |         0.3        |
|id_4      |2020-07-15    |       0.368        |         0.3        |
|id_5      |2020-07-15    |       0.668        |         0.1        |
|id_6      |2020-07-15    |       0.168        |         0.2        |
+----------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Another example with this DF:

`val df = Seq(("id_1", Map("v1" -> 0.368, "v2" -> 0.5), "2020-07-15", 16, 15),("id_1", Map("v1" -> 0.564, "v2" -> 0.78), "2020-07-15", 17, 18),("id_2", Map("v1" -> 0.468, "v2" -> 0.3), "2020-07-15", 16, 15),("id_2", Map("v1" -> 0.657, "v2" -> 0.65), "2020-07-15", 17, 18)).toDF("id", "values", "creation date", "leadTime", "span")`

Output in below format:

```
| id  |creation date| final_v1_16_15_wk | final_v1_17_18_wk |final_v2_16_15_wk | final_v2_17_18_wk | 
|id_1 | 2020-07-15 |      0.368         |      0.564      |    0.5  | 0.78 | 
|id_2 | 2020-07-15 |      0.468         |      0.657      |    0.3  | 0.65 |
```

Tried to generate column name/value using below logic but it did not work:

```
val modDF = finalDF.withColumn("final_" + newFinalDF("values").getItem(0).getItem("_1") + "_" + newFinalDF("leadTime") + "_" + newFinalDF("span") + "_wk", $"values".getItem(0).getItem("_2"));
```

Comment: so the issue is only creating column name?

Comment: @koiralo yes, main issue is with creating column names using combination of other column values. I added another example in my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer to comment

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK
import spark.implicits._

val df30 = Seq(
  ("id_1", Map("v1" -> 0.368, "v2" -> 0.5), "2020-07-15", 16, 15),
  ("id_1", Map("v1" -> 0.564, "v2" -> 0.78), "2020-07-15", 17, 18),
  ("id_2", Map("v1" -> 0.468, "v2" -> 0.3), "2020-07-15", 16, 15),
  ("id_2", Map("v1" -> 0.657, "v2" -> 0.65), "2020-07-15", 17, 18))
  .toDF("id", "values", "creation date", "leadTime", "span")

val df31 = df30.groupBy("id", "creation date")
  .agg(
    collect_list(col("values")).alias("values"),
    collect_list(col("leadTime")).alias("leadTime"),
    collect_list(col("span")).alias("span")
  ).persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)

val leadTimeArray = df31.select('leadTime).first.getAs[WrappedArray[Int]](0).toArray
val spanArray = df31.select('span).first.getAs[WrappedArray[Int]](0).toArray
val valuesArrayNew = df31.select('values).first.getAs[WrappedArray[Map[String, Float]]](0).toList

val newCols = valuesArrayNew
  .zipWithIndex
  .flatMap{case(v, i) => v.keys.map(k => s"final_${k}_${leadTimeArray(i)}_${spanArray(i)}_wk")}

val resDF = newCols.foldLeft(df31){(tempDF, colName) =>
    tempDF.withColumn(colName, 
      col("values")(newCols.indexOf(colName) / 2)(if (colName.contains("v1")) "v1" else "v2"))
}.drop("values", "leadTime", "span")


resDF.show(false)
//    +----+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
//    |id  |creation date|final_v1_16_15_wk|final_v2_16_15_wk|final_v1_17_18_wk|final_v2_17_18_wk|
//    +----+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
//    |id_1|2020-07-15   |0.368            |0.5              |0.564            |0.78             |
//    |id_2|2020-07-15   |0.468            |0.3              |0.657            |0.65             |
//    +----+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
df3.unpersist()
```

Comment: Thank you for responding back, I just updated the question with another example which has multiple rows for same "id" with different value in "leadtime" and span" column.

Comment: |  id  |creation date| final_v1_16_15_wk | final_v1_17_18_wk | final_v2_16_15_wk | 
    final_v2_17_18_wk  |
    +------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
  |id_1  |2020-07-15   |       0.368       |         0.564     |         0.5       |         0.78       |

  |id_2  |2020-07-15   |       0.468       |         0.657     |         0.3       |         0.65       |

Comment: please, see second answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mvasyliv , it is working as expected.

Comment: I tried above logic on very large dataset but these steps are very slow: `val leadTimeArray = df31.select('leadTime).first.getAs[WrappedArray[Int]](0).toArray
val spanArray = df31.select('span).first.getAs[WrappedArray[Int]](0).toArray
val valuesArrayNew = df31.select('values).first.getAs[WrappedArray[Map[String, Float]]](0).toList` even `df31.first` is very slow

Comment: could we optimize this logic to transform while processing each row in data frame?

Comment: try with persist , unpersist. Do you can show picture Spark performance monitoring & profiling?

Comment: mkl - Hello! Do you try last version?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, ya I tried latest version as well, it worked as expected. I found out issue in my script for slowness and fixed it. Your both logic working fine on larger dataset as well. Thanks a lot for quick reply and your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


val df = Seq(
  ("id_1", Map("v1" -> 0.368, "v2" -> 0.5), "2020-07-15", 16, 15),
  ("id_2", Map("v1" -> 0.368, "v2" -> 0.4), "2020-07-15", 16, 15),
  ("id_3", Map("v1" -> 0.468, "v2" -> 0.3), "2020-07-15", 16, 15),
  ("id_4", Map("v1" -> 0.368, "v2" -> 0.3), "2020-07-15", 16, 15),
  ("id_5", Map("v1" -> 0.668, "v2" -> 0.1), "2020-07-15", 16, 15),
  ("id_6", Map("v1" -> 0.168, "v2" -> 0.2), "2020-07-15", 16, 15)
).toDF("id", "values", "creation date", "leadTime", "span")

val c1 = df.select('leadTime).first.getInt(0)
val c2 = df.select('span).first.getInt(0)

val df1 = df
  .select('id,
    col("creation date"),
    col("values")("v1").as("v1"),
    col("values")("v2").as("v2"))
  .withColumnRenamed("v1", s"final_v1_${c1}_${c2}_wk")
  .withColumnRenamed("v2", s"final_v2_${c1}_${c2}_wk")


df1.show(false)
//  +----+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
//  |id  |creation date|final_v1_16_15_wk|final_v2_16_15_wk|
//  +----+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
//  |id_1|2020-07-15   |0.368            |0.5              |
//  |id_2|2020-07-15   |0.368            |0.4              |
//  |id_3|2020-07-15   |0.468            |0.3              |
//  |id_4|2020-07-15   |0.368            |0.3              |
//  |id_5|2020-07-15   |0.668            |0.1              |
//  |id_6|2020-07-15   |0.168            |0.2              |
//  +----+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+


// other variant
val df3 = df
  .withColumn(s"final_v1_${c1}_${c2}_wk", col("values")("v1"))
  .withColumn(s"final_v2_${c1}_${c2}_wk", col("values")("v2"))
  .select('id,
    col("creation date"),
    col(s"final_v1_${c1}_${c2}_wk"),
    col(s"final_v2_${c1}_${c2}_wk")
  )
```

Comment: Thank you @mvasyliv, it was helpful. I have one more question, what If I have multiple rows for same "id" with different value in "leadtime" and span" column, how can I group those in single row with different column?

Comment: Something like this: `val df = Seq(("id_1", Map("v1" -> 0.368, "v2" -> 0.5), "2020-07-15", 16, 15),("id_1", Map("v1" -> 0.368, "v2" -> 0.4), "2020-07-15", 17, 18),("id_2", Map("v1" -> 0.468, "v2" -> 0.3), "2020-07-15", 16, 15),("id_2", Map("v1" -> 0.368, "v2" -> 0.3), "2020-07-15", 17, 18)).toDF("id", "values", "creation date", "leadTime", "span")`

Comment: iv "values" your also have diff values?

Comment: "values" map would have same keys like "v1" & "v2" but it could have different values based on combination of span and leadTime column: I updated above DF: `val df = Seq(("id_1", Map("v1" -> 0.368, "v2" -> 0.5), "2020-07-15", 16, 15),("id_1", Map("v1" -> 0.564, "v2" -> 0.78), "2020-07-15", 17, 18),("id_2", Map("v1" -> 0.468, "v2" -> 0.3), "2020-07-15", 16, 15),("id_2", Map("v1" -> 0.657, "v2" -> 0.65), "2020-07-15", 17, 18)).toDF("id", "values", "creation date", "leadTime", "span")`